# what is suitable event in javascript that active when all DOM activated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i want to use moment for date in my page.
i have input with type hidden that contain Gregorian format of date, and i want to convert it into Persian date after my page loaded and put result in another input text.but i don't know what event should i use to handle this... can somebody help me?
here is my code:

```
var value=document.getElementById("dateInputHidden")
    $(document).ready(function (value) {
        var m = moment(value, 'M/D/YYYY');
        var perDate = m.format('jYYYY/jM/jD');
        document.getElementById("dateInput").value = perDate
    })
```

this was my function in Javascript that loaded document.ready event but its not working after my page entirely loaded.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label> contractExpiretion</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PersianContractExpiration"  id="dateInput" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ContractExpiration" onload="convertToEngDate(this.value)" id="dateInputHidden"  value="@Model.ContractExpiration.ToShortDateString()"   />

            </div>
```

I think it's document.ready event it invoke when all HTML tag loaded completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that code in document ready function like this

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        //your code...
    });
</script>
```